# How to get a number value from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I Am having trouble with this, i have table from mysql named person with fields id, name, and person_room. I also have this table called room with fields of roomid, name and capacity. i want to call a data from field capacity of table room. but it shows Resource id #7

here is my code:

```
$check_room_capacity = "SELECT capacity from room WHERE roomid = '".$oroom."'";
$check_user_capacity = mysql_query($check_room_capacity);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_capacity);

$check_room = "SELECT id from person WHERE person_room = '".$oroom."'";
$check_user_room = mysql_query($check_room);

    if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_room) => $check_user_capacity){
        echo "room is loaded please try another room";
    }

//then code here to insert it if the number of person 
//is less than the room capacity
```

I tried to echo this thing $check_user_capacity to know its value but it shows resource id#7. Do you guys have any idea?

The other thing is, why my php don't accept this operation '=>' and '<=' it always underlined in color red?

Comment: Do you realize what `mysql_query` function returns? If not - why haven't you even tried to read the corresponding documentation page? "Do you guys have any idea?" --- of course we do!! Every time you are using any function - check its documentation page!

Comment: $rows['capacity'] is the number you are looking for.

Comment: sorry but i am new in doing this code.

Comment: then why is it => and <= errors and underlined red?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() statement returns a resource pointer to the result set, not the data itself. You'll need to use mysql_fetch_array() in order to retrieve the actual data in the table.

```
$old_ip = mysql_query("SELECT current_ip FROM members WHERE id='$id'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($old_ip);
$result_old_ip = $row['current_ip'];
```

Comment: i tried this one but when rows of person and the capacity is equal, still it accepts to insert the data.

Comment: seems like the one i am comparing if they are >= to is maybe a string and the other one is a number how can we convert a string to a number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$check_room_capacity = "SELECT capacity from room WHERE roomid = '".$oroom."'";
    $check_user_capacity = mysql_query($check_room_capacity);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_capacity);

    $check_room = "SELECT id from person WHERE person_room = '".$oroom."'";
    $check_user_room = mysql_query($check_room);

        if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_room) >= $rows['capacity']){
            echo "room is loaded please try another room";
        }
```